# On the weak and strong convergence of an iterative sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

I have some difficulties in the following problem.

I would like to thank for all kind help and construction.

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional real Hilbert space and $F: H\rightarrow H$ be a mapping. Suppose that there exists $\gamma>0$ such that
$$
\langle F(u)-F(v), u-v\rangle\geq \gamma\|F(u)-F(v)\|^2\quad \forall u,v \in H.
$$
Let $u_0\in H$ and $\lambda\in (0, 2\gamma)$ and $\{u_n\}$
be a sequence given by
$$
u_{n+1}=u_n-\lambda F(u_n) \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.
$$
I would like to construct the above mapping $F$ such that 
the equation $F(u)=0$ **has a solution** and
the iterative sequence $\{u_n\}$ **converges weakly** to **some solution** of the latter equation, **but not strongly**.

**Note.** We can prove that the iterative sequence $\{u_n\}$ converges weakly to some solution of the equation $F(u)=0$ provided that the latter equation has a solution.

Let $u_*$ be a solution of $F(u)=0$. We observe that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\|u_{n+1}-u_*\|^2&=&\|u_n-\lambda F(u_n)-u_*+\lambda F(u_*)\|^2\\
                 &=& \|u_n-u_*\|^2-2\lambda\langle u_n-u_*, F(u_n)-F(u_*)\rangle+\lambda^2\|F(u_n)-F(u_*)\|^2\\
                 &\leq& \|u_n-u_*\|^2-2\lambda\gamma\|F(u_n)-F(u_*)\|^2+\lambda^2\|F(u_n)-F(u_*)\|^2\\
                 &=&\|u_n-u_*\|^2-\lambda(2\gamma-\lambda)\|F(u_n)\|^2\\
                 &=&\|u_n-u_*\|^2-\frac{2\gamma-\lambda}{\lambda}\|u_n-u_{n+1}\|^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
From these inequalities we deduce that

- $\{\|u_n-u_*\|\}$ is monotonically decreasing and so it is convergent.
- $\{\|u_n-u_{n+1}\|\}$ and $\{\|F(u_n)\|\}$ tend to $0$.
- $\{u_n\}$ is bounded and so it has a subsequence $\{u_{n_k}\}$
  converges weakly to $\bar{u}$.
- $\bar{u}$ is a solution of $F(u)=0$, and so $\{u_n\}$ converges weakly to $\bar{u}$.

Comment: There is a problem with your question: your iterative method does not converge (weakly). Take $H = \mathbb{R}^2$, $F = \mathrm{diag}(\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2)$, for some $\Lambda_2 > \Lambda_1$. Then, your iteration is linear and described by the matrix $\mathrm{diag}(1-\lambda\,\Lambda_1, 1-\lambda\,\Lambda_2)$. For convergence, you need $\lambda \in (0, 2/\Lambda_2)$ and not $(0, 2\,\Lambda_1)$.

Comment: Dear gerw. Thank you for your comments. Remember that the mapping $F$ must satisfy the condition $$\langle F(u)-F(v), u-v\rangle\geq \gamma\|F(u)-F(v)\|^2\quad \forall u,v \in H$$ for some $\gamma>0$. The mapping $F$ in your counterexample seem not to satisfy our condition.

Comment: It satisfies this condition, but for $\gamma = 1/\Lambda_2$ (not $\gamma = \Lambda_1$) and then everything is fine.

Comment: @gerw: Thank you again for your interesting comments. Here we need $F$ must satisfy $$
\langle F(u)-F(v), u-v\rangle\geq \gamma\|F(u)-F(v)\|^2\quad \forall u,v \in H 
$$ but not $$
\langle F(u)-F(v), u-v\rangle\geq \gamma\|u-v\|^2\quad \forall u,v \in H 
$$

Comment: @grew: In your counterexample, in order to have
$$
\langle F(u)-F(v), u-v\rangle\geq \gamma\|F(u)-F(v)\|^2\quad \forall u,v \in H=\mathbb{R}^2
$$
we must have (choose $u=(x_1, y_1), v=(x_2, y_2)$)
$$
\lambda_1(x_1-x_2)^2+\lambda_2(y_1-y_2)^2\geq \gamma(\lambda_1^2(x_1-x_2)^2+\lambda_2^2(y_1-y_2)^2).
$$
From this we deduce that $\lambda_1, \lambda_2\in (0,\frac{1}{\gamma}]$.
Therefore $(0, 2\gamma)\subset (0, \frac{2}{\lambda_2})\subset (0,\frac{2}{\lambda_1})$.

Comment: @grew: Dear Sir. Do you have any comments in my question? Thank you again for your construction.

Comment: If have thought about it a little bit, but didn't found a counterexample. How do you prove the weak convergence of the iterative scheme?

Comment: Is $F$ assumed to be continuous? Can you include here the proof that the sequence converges weakly to a solution?

Comment: @grew: I included a short proof that the iterative sequence converges weakly to a solution.

Comment: @timur: I included the short proof of the weak convergence of the iterative sequence. From the Cauchy Schwarz in equality and the following inequality
$$
\langle F(u)-F(v), u-v\rangle\geq \gamma\|F(u)-F(v)\|^2,
$$
we imply that
$$
\gamma\|F(u)-F(v)\|^2\leq \|F(u)-F(v)\|\|u-v\|,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\|F(u)-F(v)\|\leq \frac{1}{\gamma}\|F(u)-F(v)\|.
$$
Hence $F$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks! So your question is basically if $\bar u = u^*$?

Comment: @timur: Okie. But my problem may have a lot of solutions.

Comment: I would like to ask more comments and kind help in this question? How can we find the help?